# Pass value where some value

Tags: java

I would like to pass 2 values from one method in to another one and set one value where the other value from first method equals to value from second method.

Here is my code and i'll comment the lines where i need to pass values:

```
public class updateResults {

String b1 = "48";

//String "path" is the value i want to pass
//String "number" is the value which i send to check where string "path goes"
   void updateResults(String path, String number) throws FileNotFoundException,  IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


            XSSFRow row0 = sheet.getRow(0);
            XSSFCell cell0 = row0.getCell(0);
            XSSFCell cell1 = row0.getCell(1);
            XSSFCell cell2 = row0.getCell(2);
            XSSFCell cell3 = row0.getCell(3);
            XSSFCell cell4 = row0.getCell(4);
            XSSFCell cell5 = row0.getCell(5);
            XSSFCell cell6 = row0.getCell(6);
            XSSFCell cell7 = row0.getCell(7);
            XSSFCell cell8 = row0.getCell(8);
            XSSFCell cell9 = row0.getCell(9);
            XSSFCell cell10 = row0.getCell(10);
            XSSFCell cell11 = row0.getCell(11);
            XSSFCell cell12 = row0.getCell(12);
            XSSFCell cell13 = row0.getCell(13);
            cell0.setCellValue("1"); //If string "number" is "1" String "path" should be set to this cell
            cell1.setCellValue("2");//If string "number" is "2" String "path" should be set to this cell
            cell2.setCellValue("3");
            cell3.setCellValue("4");
            cell4.setCellValue("5");
            cell5.setCellValue("9");
            cell6.setCellValue("11");
            cell7.setCellValue("76");
            cell8.setCellValue("43");
            cell9.setCellValue("22");
            cell10.setCellValue("");
            cell11.setCellValue("");
            cell12.setCellValue("");
            cell13.setCellValue("");
    //NOTE: i have  more than 10.000 cells and they are not in ASC or DESC order.
```

I have limited java knowledge so i don't know how can i set in example `XSSFCell cell13 = row0.getCell(13);` to `XSSFCell 13 = row0.getCell(13);`.

Any help will be appreciated.

To make it more clear:

I have 2 strings that I send from one method in to this one above:
Lets say:
    String path = "box"
    String number = "21"

I want to set `path` to `cell3`

```
`cell3.setCellValue("21");`
`cell4.setCellValue("4");`
`cell4.setCellValue("15");`
`cell4.setCellValue("1532");`
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cell5.setCellValue("6");` and `cell6.setCellValue("7");` and so on...?
Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you trying to set the path to equal a cell? Can you not just say `path=row0.getCell(number)` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Could you try to make it more clear?

Comment: You cannot change the callers `path` reference, that's an immutable `String`. You could `return` a `String` or you could pass a non-immutable type (like `StringBuilder`).

Comment: If you have `String path = "box"` and `String number = "21"`, how you decide that `cell3` (and not cell1 or cell4?) value should be set. Also, you say you "want to set path to cell3", but you then do `cell3.setCellValue("21");`, which is setting cell3 to the same value as of `number`... Unclear!